# OAuth(2) and friends

Tags: authentication, reference-request

I've worked on low-level security (side-channel attacks etc.) for years and have a PhD in crypto. Web security is something I've never needed to touch beyond knowing how the TLS handshake works with various cipher suites.

I'm starting a role where I'm expecting to also do work on mobile app security. It seems like e.g. the OAuth standards are split over a large bunch of RFCs and most online tutorials are written for dummies and are doing a great job avoiding telling what sorts of cryptographic primitives are used and where. In other words leave out material that allows doing your own reasoning about security.

My question is whether there are any good papers (e g. from CCS¹ or S&P³) or sources that go in depth through the actual cryptography, the assumed models for the attacker and the design choices made in the protocols? In other words what to read to get up to speed quickly?

---

¹ CCS = ACM³ Conference on Computer and Communications Security.

² S&P = IEEE⁴ Symposium on Security and Privacy.

³ ACM = Association for Computing Machinery.

⁴ IEEE = Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers.

Comment: [This report](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01229) may be worth a look?

Comment: Welcome to crypto.SE. In principle, reference requests are off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), we prefer direct questions on crypto points. That could be a question for [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 1) The question could be better answered at Information Security SE. 2) The question expects opinion based answers.